# Converting R dataframes

Tags: r

I am using R.
I want to convert a dataframe which has 3 columns and 72 rows
to
a dataframe which has 9 columns and 9 rows. How can I do this. I stuck on this for many days and cannot think of a good solution. Thanks!

[This is the raw dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPAsy.png)
[The output I wish to have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocwq0.png)

Comment: Try `xtabs(weight ~ from + to, segs)`

Comment: It will help people answer your questions if you can provide example data in the form of code instead of as pictures. The easiest way to do this would be to run `dput(segs)` and paste the output into the body of your question. This will give others a recipe to quickly and exactly recreate your data.

Comment: Thanks Jon. Will do it next time! Cheers